# Python datetime switching between US and UK date formats

Tags: python, python-datetime

I'm using matplotlib to plot some data imported from CSV files. These files have the following format:

```
Date,Time,A,B
25/07/2016,13:04:31,5,25550
25/07/2016,13:05:01,0,25568
....
01/08/2016,19:06:43,0,68425
```

The dates are formatted as they would be in the UK, i.e. `%d/%m/%Y`. The end result is to have two plots: one of how `A` changes with time, and one of how `B` changes with time. I'm importing the data from the CSV like so:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import sys
...

def analyze_log(file, y):
    data = csv2rec(open(file, 'rb'))

    fig = plt.figure()

    date_vec = [datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d').date() for x in data['date']]
    print date_vec[0]
    print date_vec[len(date_vec)-1]

    time_vec = [datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d %X').time() for x in data['time']]
    print time_vec[0]
    print time_vec[len(time_vec)-1]

    datetime_vec = [datetime.combine(d, t) for d, t in zip(date_vec, time_vec)]
    print datetime_vec[0]
    print datetime_vec[len(datetime_vec)-1]

    y_vec = data[y]
    plt.plot(datetime_vec, y_vec)

    ...
    # formatters, axis headers, etc.
    ...
    return plt
```

And all was working fine before 01 August. However, since then, matplotlib is trying to plot my 01/08/2016 data points as 2016-01-08 (08 Jan)!

I get a plotting error because it tries to plot from January to July:

```
RuntimeError: RRuleLocator estimated to generate 4879 ticks from 2016-01-08 09:11:00+00:00 to 2016-07-29 16:22:34+00:00:
```

exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS * 2 (2000)

What am I doing wrong here? The results of the print statements in the code above are:

```
2016-07-25
2016-01-08 #!!!!
13:04:31
19:06:43
2016-07-25 13:04:31
2016-01-08 19:06:43 #!!!!
```

Comment: You're using `'%Y-%m-%d'` in `strptime`..?

Comment: @Phillip When I put `%d/%m/%Y` in the format I get the error: `ValueError: time data '2016-07-25' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'`

Comment: @Frangipanes: is your input using a mix of formats then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, my input is only using the UK format. I've double checked this.

Comment: Are you certain that `csv2rec` doesn't temper with the dates? I'm curious because the [documentation talks about a `dayfirst` property](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec).

Comment: @Phillip Thanks! Setting that parameter did the trick. If you'd like to write that up as an answer I'll mark it up as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib's [csv2rec](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec) function parses your dates already and tries to be intelligent when it comes to parsing dates. The function has two options to influence the parsing, `dayfirst` should help here:

> dayfirst: default is False so that MM-DD-YY has precedence over DD-MM-YY.
>
> yearfirst: default is False so that MM-DD-YY has precedence over YY-MM-DD.
>
> See http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-b95ce2094d189a89f80f5ae52a05b4ab7b41af47 for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You're using strings in `%d/%m/%Y` format but you've given the format specifier as `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: When I put `%d/%m/%Y` in the format I get an error: `ValueError: time data '2016-07-25' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'`

Comment: '2016-07-25' doesn't appear in the input or the code you've shown. Where does that error occur?

Comment: When I change `date_vec = [datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d').date() for x in data['date']]` to `date_vec = [datetime.strptime(str(x), '%d/%m/%Y').date() for x in data['date']]`. I don't understand it either, but Python tells me that the data it's reading has `-` when the raw CSV has `/`. The `dtype` of the date and time fields are both `0`.

Comment: Does the matplot csv reading function do any automatic conversion on dates? `datetime.strptime(str(x), '%d/%m/%Y').date()` works fine when I'm reading x from a simple txt file.